# I want to slice my pandas data frame with a variable that contains a pd.date_range, but it is returning Nan for my data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have loaded data from yahoo finance which includes the headings date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj close. The date is my index for the data frame, and I want to be able to sort this data using the index(date).

The variable month will give an array of the dates that I need, and it will print. The problem is I get Nan values for my data.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("cde_data.csv",index_col='Date')
month = pd.date_range('2010-08-01','2016-08-01',freq='m')

print(df.ix[month.values])
```

This is the output that I get (I only posted the first 4 rows to save space)

```
            Open  High  Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close
Date
2010-08-31   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN

2010-09-30   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN

2010-10-31   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN

2010-11-30   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN
```

This the df.head()

```
              Open    High     Low   Close  Volume   Adj Close
Date
1990-04-12  26.875  26.875  26.625  26.625    6100  250.576036
1990-04-16  26.500  26.750  26.375  26.750     500  251.752449
1990-04-17  26.750  26.875  26.750  26.875    2300  252.928863
1990-04-18  26.875  26.875  26.500  26.625    3500  250.576036
1990-04-19  26.500  26.750  26.500  26.750     700  251.752449
```

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: provide df.head() to get help

Comment: I added df,head

Comment: `month` contains the "end of the month" dates. Are you sure you have values corresponding those dates in the dataframe? `df.ix[month]` works fine when I try with matching indices.

Comment: Yes these values are present, I even switched the frequency to days and still get Nan

Comment: @ayhan is right, there are dates in your month variable that are not in the indexes of the data.frame `df`. Also if you are after the first days of the month then you may want to do `month = pd.date_range('2010-08-01','2016-08-01',freq='MS')`, instead of `month = pd.date_range('2010-08-01','2016-08-01',freq='m')`. But even with this, you still have dates like ***January 1st*** for which you do not have data, because it is the first day of the year and markets close.

Comment: There are also firsts of the month that fell on saturdays and sundays. You should work specifically with business days.

Comment: I tried the dates 1990-04-16 to 1990-4-19 which is listed above in the df.head and I still get Nan

Comment: If this is ticker ***cde***, then you're doing something wrong. I have downloaded that same dataset and both `df.ix['1990-04-19']` and `df.ix['1990-04-16']` are working for me and returning results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is not of type datetime but object. Convert it before using it:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')
```